# Maintainable mapping approach to JdbcTemplate query with joins

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I have 3 tables which correspond to 3 Java objects:

- Object A (Table A)
- Object B (Table B)
- Object C (Table C)

I will query `Table A` and `JOIN` on `Table B` and `Table C`. I've only used the JdbcTemplate to query for `Table A` and have used Spring's `BeanPropertyRowMapper` to map the result to `Object A`. But now I would like to `JOIN` the remaining tables.

So I've created a new Java object that stores the 3 tables mentioned above. This looks like:

```java
public class AllTables {

    private ObjectA tableA;

    private ObjectB tableB;

    private ObjectC tableC;
}
```

And an example query would look like:

```sql
SELECT tableA.*, tableB.*, tableC.* 
FROM table_a tableA 
JOIN tableB 
    ON tableB.ref_id = tableA.id 
JOIN table_c tableC 
    ON tableC.ref_id = tableA.id;
```

Does Spring provide any facilities to auto-map these tables / columns with their respective Java equivalent object?
I do not want to manually map the `ResultSet` and if I have to, is there a way to pass a `ResultSet` to `BeanPropertyRowMapper` manually to leverage the column mapping?

Comment: Yes - [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) and [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-join-types) should help.

Comment: So unless you implement Spring JPA as advised above the solution you're looking for doesn't exist. The only way to do it would be with a custom `RowMapper`.

Comment: @mohammedkhan I've ended up writing my own `ResultSetExtractor` that uses reflection to map rows to entities, and also supports the JPA API (`@JoinColumn`, `@Column`, `@OneToMany`, etc...).